# How can I stretch wrapper div according to ul list?

Tags: css, list, html, html-lists

My wrapper div css;

```
.post-wrapper{
  width:200px;
   min-height:50px;
  }
```

ul list css for .post-wrapper;

```
.post-wrapper ul{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:200px;
 }

.post-wrapper ul li{
   margin-bottom:2px;
   padding:0;
   list-style:none;
   text-align:center;
   width:200px; 
   float:left;   
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
 <ul>
   <li>Item-1</li>
   <li>Item-2</li>
   <li>Item-3</li>
   <li>Item-4</li>
   <li>Item-5</li>
   <li>Item-6</li>
   <li>Item-7</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

There is no problem for 5 list item (li) but after 5 post-wrapper don't stretch. How can solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you mean stretch vertically?  And where's your html - the css doesn't appear to have any problems (assuming you want to stretch vertically).

Comment: yes vertically. Added to html @cale_b

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem may be the `float:left` on the li element
Try:
1. add `position:relative` to the wrapper container
2. add a clearing div to the bottom of the wrapper

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
 <ul>
   <li>Item-1</li>
   <li>Item-2</li>
   <li>Item-3</li>
   <li>Item-4</li>
   <li>Item-5</li>
   <li>Item-6</li>
   <li>Item-7</li>
 <div style="clear:both; width:100%"></div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

1. remove float from li

Comment: I don't think it is best practice to add DOM elements to solve presentational issues... It shouldn't be suggested!

Comment: Don't downvote the answer when it contains 3 potential solutions to backtracing the problem. We have to allow the OP to do some work in determining what the "best practices" are for their own project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearfix technique on your unordered list element. Be aware that this technique relies on CSS generated content (`:before`, `:after`) and therefore will only work with IE8+. Other modern browsers will be fine.

Depending on the context of your wrapper, floating the wrapper may or may not break your design. This technique will allow you to stretch your wrapper `div` without floating it.

```
.post-wrapper ul {
     margin:   0;
     padding:  0;
     width:    200px;
 }

 .post-wrapper ul:after {
    content:      ".";
    overflow:     hidden;
    display:      block;
    text-indent:  -9999px;
    height:       0;
    clear:        both;
    visibility:   hidden;
 }
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/DajuR/) of a working example. The red background has been added on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float: left` on inner elements, you need to do something that will cause the OUTER element to clear the floated elements.

While there are a few ways to accomplish this, the simplest method in this case would be to use `overflow: hidden` on the `.post-wrapper ul` element:

```
.post-wrapper ul{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:200px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Float both your `ul` and your `div` left, that should resolve the issue.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/sCAdj/

The other approach is to add a dummy list item that clears the float:

```
<li style="float:none;clear:left"></li>
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/sCAdj/1/